# Submitting a contact form using AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to make a AJAX form, which one click, fires the URI: '/send/contact' and I use https://github.com/Nikic/FastRoute for routing, and this is how I have defined the route:

`['POST', '/send/contact', ['HassanAlthaf\PersonalWebsite\Controllers\ContactTool', 'submitForm']],`

And this is the method that runs:

```
public function submitForm()
{
    $sender = $this->httpRequest->getParameter('fullName');
    $email = $this->httpRequest->getParameter('email');
    $subject = $this->httpRequest->getParameter('subject');
    $message = $this->httpRequest->getParameter('message');
    $ipAddress = $this->httpRequest->getIpAddress();

    $result = $this->contactFormService->saveForm($sender, $email, $subject, $message, $ipAddress);

    if ($result === true) {
        $this->httpResponse->setContent("<div id=\"content\"><div class=\"success\">You have successfully sent the message.</div></div>");
    } else {
        $this->httpResponse->setContent("<div id=\"content\">" . json_encode($result) . "</div>");
    }
}
```

The jQuery code that handles the form:

```
$("#contact-form").submit( function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var $form = $(this),
        sender = $form.find('input[name="fullName"]').val(),
        email = $form.find('input[name="emmail"]').val(),
        subject = $form.find('input[name="subject"]').val(),
        message = $form.find('textarea[name="message"]').val(),
        url = $form.attr('action');

    var posting = $.post(url, {
        sender: sender,
        email: email,
        subject: subject,
        message: message
    });

    posting.done( function(data) {
        var content = $(data).find('#content');
        $("#result").empty().append(content);
    });

});
```

And finally, my form HTML code:

```
                <form class="contact-form" method="post" action="send/contact" id="contact-form">
                    <input type="text" name="fullName" class="input-field" placeholder="Your full name" maxlegth="50" required>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="input-field" placeholder="Your email" maxlength="100" required>
                    <input type="text" name="subject" class="input-field" placeholder="Subject" maxlength="75" required>
                    <textarea rows="4" type="text" name="message" class="input-field text-area" placeholder="Your message" maxlength="2000"></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send Message" class="button">
                </form>
```

However, it doesn't give any response. I click it, it stays all idle as if it was just some image. Any idea why? I checked the database, and no changes. It also doesn't throw out any validation checks or anything.

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I forgot to include that. @JayBlanchard

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: Fixed this issue. @JayBlanchard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, it was a simple fix. My PHP code expected something like `$_POST['fullName'];` and therefore, had to change `sender: sender,` to `fullName: fullName,` and change places where I used the word `sender.`

Answer (score 0):

Your code works flawlessly, but you have a typo in this line.

```
 email = $form.find('input[name="emmail"]').val(),<--- 2 m
 email = $form.find('input[name="email"]').val(),<--- should be
```

Tested the form, it return data from the server as expected.

Comment: It still gives blank stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `return false;` at the end of your submit function instead of `event.preventDefault();`

If that doesn't work, use `console.log(data);` so you will get the response in your console.

Also, why not just use `$("form").serialize();` to generate a query string from inputs?

`$("#result").html(content);` should also be sufficient as it replaces its contents.

Comment: `return false;` = `event.preventDefault()`; it is the same thing.

Comment: [`return false` and `event.preventDefault()` are *not* the same thing.](https://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/) @mdamia

Comment: @Jez [It's not hard to earn enough rep to make comments.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: What I meant to say, that they both prevent the event from being triggered. In this case, prevent form from being submitted.  @JayBlanchard